# Jogani Maa Who Is Chinnmastika?

Tags: devi, goddess, chinnamasta

Am obsessed w/ Chinnmasta Maa so constantly looking up stuffs bout her, and for several months now, been coming across lots of artworks of Gujarati Jogani Maa, Jogni Maa. I’m not from Gujarat so never had heard of this form of Devi.

Who clearly seems to be Chinnmastika Maa however is described as “satvic” take on her, or something. But looks very much the Tantric MahaVidya Chinnmasta, apparently derived from Himachal Pradesh.

Is this historically just a different form of the Tantric goddess herself ?

Is there different stories and mythology for her ?

Googling excessively as usual but can’t read or understand Gujarati at all so couldn’t peruse the info properly.

They have boatloads of Jogani Maa garba dandiya stuffs too (seems like such a strange juxtaposition of cheerful dance like that w/ self-behead image )

Any info is greatly appreciated thx

[image]

[image]

Comment: The picture looks exactly like Maa Chinnamasta. Well, i must say it is Maa Chinnamasta. But, you are saying the name of the goddess is Jogani Mata. May be it's pronounced like that. Because in Bengali also, we pronounce "Yo" as "Jo" sometimes. So, it might be Jogini Or Yogini Mata. Though m not sure. Dakini and Yogini are the 2 Shaktis and friends of Maa Chinnamasta. Whom you can see in both sides of her. They are the friends of Mata Parvati known as Jayā (जया) and Vijayā (विजया) respectively.

Comment: @Savdy Yeah it’s weird, it’s so clearly her. But the puja rituals are described as different saatvic & non Tantric stuff, like they’re trying so hard to differentiate from the actual Goddess  Apparently derived from Himachal Pradesh form of Devi who obviously be Chinnmastika of MahaVidyas. I’m not from Gujarat or Bengal so couldn’t exactly clarify what I was reading  Searched on here for Jogani Maa & didn’t turn up anything, so posted the question. I’m not South Indian either but w/ the South socials I follow, they’re so clear w/ the Devi mytho source. However not the same w/ this stuff.

Comment: @.devibhakt. well may they just calling her by different names and worshipping her differently because they have some local folk story, who knows. But, Mata Chinnamasta is one of the ferocious aspects of Mata. So, wrongly worshipping her can be disastrous. But, even so Maa Kali is also called Tamsik but Sri Kālika Puran states that her teeths are Sattva which are holding Rajas and Tavas (Her tongue) in control.May be it's something like that.I guess only a local gujrati, can tell about this. Bdw, my bengali reference was just for the pronunciation purpose. We worship her in tantrik way only.

Comment: @Savdy Yeah totally, makes sense. & I will try look up more for my own curiosity. Thx for the comments and input 

Comment: You are most welcome. .. well if you get some thing then you can answer your own question also for every one else to know. . Gn. Tc . Cya..

Comment: The worship of Mahavidyas is deeply rooted inside the Tantra. Omitting Tantrika aspects & replacing it with Vaidika equivalents for worshipping Mahavidyas will yield no results. The only Mahavidyas who can be worshipped in Vaidika way are Durga using the Jatavedagni sukta & Lakshmi using the Srisukta.

Comment: @blue_ego Be nice to your fellow users.

Answer (score 2):

```
Is this historically just a different form of the Tantric goddess herself or is described as “satvic” take on her?
```

There is no Satwik, Tamasic or Rajasic Chinnamasta as opposed to Tara. Indeed Jogani devi and Chinnamasta devi are one and the same.

```
Is there different stories and mythology for her ?
```

No the kathamrit for Chinnamasta and Jogani are same.

```
Seems like such a strange juxtaposition of cheerful dance like that w/ self-behead image
```

That isn't any normal dance just for merry moments. Garba is originally the Lasya Nritya that Bhagwati loves herself. Thus even one of her Sahasranaam mentions her to be,

> लास्यप्रिया
> The one who loves Lasya (Garba)

Coming to the point that how can people approach such a fearsome deity without proper initiation and Guru's guidance?
This is because she is venerated as Kuldevi. Thus, worshipping Kuldevi as per Lokachara by the people in clan is must. In such cases Lokachara and the puja padhati followed in family over writes Shastras.
Scriptures support use of Lokachar in such cases.

Arthashastra of Vishnugupt Chanakya,

> शास्त्रज्ञोप्यलोकज्ञोभवेन्मूर्खतुल्य:।
> लोकज्ञता सर्वज्ञता॥
> Those who don't know Deśāchāra are fools and know nothing.

Brahmavaivart Puran, Ganapti Khand, chapter 7,

> वेदाचाराल्लौकिकाचारो बलवान् यथा पार्व्वत्युवाच ।           केवलं वेदमाश्रित्य कः करोति विनिर्णयम् ।
> बलवान् लौकिको वेदाल्लोकाचारञ्च कस्त्यजेत् ॥
> Devī Pārvatī says who else has the capability to leave Lokāchara which is as important as Vedas.

But this doesn't means one can do her Pratyakshikaran merely by following lokachar and Bhakti. One can only earn abit of her grace that's all. For getting pratyaksha darshana of Amba indeed, a proper initiation and Guru parampara is must.
Thus, many Gujaratis worship her as their Kuldevi and yet face no grave consequences. But, the person who doesn't belongs to that clan might face her wrath.

*कालिकार्पणमस्तु|*